# Request API with multi-threading in python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing

How can I request the following API with multi-threading in python? Or any ways that can request API more effective? Multi-processing? AsyncIO?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def getAPIreturn(row):
    para = row['para']
    url = f"http://localhost/search?name={para}"
    
    try:
        return_json = json.loads(requests.get(url).json)
        data = return_json['data']
        
        score = data[0]['score']
        count = data[1]['count']
        status = data[2]['status']
    except:
        score = None
        count = None
        status = None
        
    row['score'] = score
    row['count'] = count
    row['status'] = status
        
    return row

data = pd.read_csv("input.csv") 
data = data.apply(getAPIreturn, axis=1)
data.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: If you don't mind a third-party package, take a look at [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures), which will handle it for you. I don't know about using it directly with pandas' `.apply` though, so you might have to refactor it a bit.

Comment: Look into creating a ThreadPoolExecutor with a maximum number of workers that can be tweaked depending on how long each request takes on average. Multi-threading only gives the illusion of parallelism and is most suited to I/O heavy tasks (like yours). Multi-processing works on multiple cores and imo won't help much since you're not doing much work on the retrieved data.